# Need a Plugin to create a registration form for my website?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, user-registration

I need a custom registration page from for my site. I want to take some details from my regular visitor and then finally want these details in a csv or excel file. Is there is a plugin which can do this for me just like we have Contact Form 7 for Contact Page??? This question may seems common but please consider me as i am very new to wordpress.

Comment: Once you downvote you should comment a reason to down vote. Please follow some SE standards.

Comment: While I haven't downvoted this question I considered it also - this question shows little to no research effort, which, as I am sure you know, is just as much part of SE standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correclty, you are essentially asking two questions.

For one, you are looking for a solution for a customized registration- (login- / profile-) page. Also, you want to export data to .csv or .xls

As for the first issue, I'd recommend taking a look at Jeff Farthing's excellent [Theme-My-Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin.

As for the second, I know of one discontinued plugin that might be of help. I have no experience with it though. Check out [ALO Export XLS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/alo-exportxls/).
A dirty solution would be to export directly from the DB via phpMyAdmin or the like.
You might have to write your own plugin for this issue.

Comment: Pile thnx for not downvoting it... I know SE standards and i have a strong believe in them. I have searched few plugins but i am unable to find the one which gives me a csv or excel directly. Will try this as well.

Comment: i didnt find better answer than this... hence accepting the answer. Thanx a lot :)